# jquery, select one before last <tr> and then a specific <input> inside

Tags: html, jquery, forms, input, jquery-selectors

I have a structure like this

```
<div id="images_content_876454323">
 <form>
  <table>
   <tr class="target-class"></tr>
   <tr class="target-class"></tr>
   <tr class="target-class">
    <td>
     <div>
      <input/>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="target-class"></tr>
  <table>
 </form>
</div>
```

I want to select the `<input>` that is inside the 'one before last' `.target-class` with jQuery

No idea how to do that without being "hacky"

Comment: Select the `.target-class` and use a combination of [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev) and [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find). If you need help debugging the code you've got, please add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

First, close your table tag.

```
<div id="images_content_876454323">
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr class="target-class"></tr>
      <tr class="target-class"></tr>
      <tr class="target-class">
        <td>
          <div>
            <input value="textvalue"/>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="target-class"></tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

I did a example value in the input tag.

```
var table = $('tr');
console.log('inputValue', $(table).eq(2).find('input').val());
```

If you want the input value dynamically you can do a click function on eg.

```
var table = $('tr');
$("#images_content_876454323").click(function() {
  var str = $(table).eq(2).find('input').val();
  alert(str);
});
```

So you will get the current value of the input field by click on it.